# Search and update value in json file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, key-value-store

I'm trying to create a key-value paired datastore in nodejs in which I'm trying to use a json file as a database. Now I'm trying to read a particular value of key and update it or delete it.

For eg.(dummy data)

```
{
   name: 'my name',
   no:12345,
   course : {
      name: 'cname',
      id: 'cid'
   }
}
```

Now I want to change it as

```
{
   name: 'my name',
   no:12345,
   course : {
      name: 'cname1',
      id: 'cid1'
   },
   fees: {
      primaryFee: 1000,
      donation: 100,
   }
}
```

Or even delete the course key with it's value.

One way I thought of to achieve this is read the entire file and store it in a variable(json parsed). And update the value in that variable and write the whole data to the file.

But this is not efficient as it reads and writes the whole data every time of an update.

So is there any efficient approach for this to update or delete a particular key in the file itself???

Comment: If you're dealing with lots of read/writes to a file on the file-system, you should probably reconsider using a file-datasource - sounds like a DB would be more appropriate? :)

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying it for creating a file based datastore for learning purpose. It's a task given to me and I'm trying to do it efficiently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working on a file based data store, you could use FS in node.js to read and write files. The readfilesync callback returns you the whole content of the file which should be parsed as JSON and changes are to be made.

So AFAIK the only solution is to read the whole file and then update or delete the value. In the worst case scenario you will traverse O(n) when you are trying to update or deleting the key.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, even in a high-level programming language like JS, it is possible to update parts of a file, though it is usually more common in low-level programming languages like e.g. C

For node.js, check-out the official documentation of the file system module, especially the write function: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback

Other possible solutions to your problem:

1. Use a database as [eol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3761628/eol) suggested
2. Use an append-only file where you only append the updates. This is more efficient because not the whole file has to be written.
3. Split your database-file into several files (this is what databases often do below the surface)

Comment: I looked into it, but in buffer I can't parse the partial data into JSON and search for a particular key since the data is available as a string in the buffer. Thanks for the info which I could use in the future.

Comment: You have to read the whole document / file, yes. Otherwise you cannot search for a key or parse it into JSON. But once you have it read, you could update it if you know the exact position in the file where each JSON property is located. As you already see, it becomes fairly complicated. You could though implement your own JSON parsing mechanism and append to the file lines like `jsonObject.property1 = blablabla` and then construct the JSON Object from the original one plus all added lines. This is like an extended/altered key-value store.

Answer (score 0):

You've discovered why databases are so complicated ;)

There isn't really a good way to update a json file without completely reading & parsing the data, editing and then writing the result again.

If you're looking for a simple file database, have a look at sqlite

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and the reason why we're going to db instead of a simple file based db. By your answer, are you saying that what I'm asking is impossible???

Comment: I wouldn't say impossible but what you're doing (full read, edit, full write) is definitely the most bug proof way of doing it. You could write a custom file reader and parser but that would be an insane amount of work compared to using something a sqlite (which also works with a file) or an alternative database that also works with a file

Comment: So there is an alternative way for doing specific updates??? (Even with bugs or problems). I'm just trying to explore the possibilites.

Comment: Ye sure, you could read the contents of the file and make changes to it yourself. Say you want to add a new key, you could perfectly well just add it at the end before the trailing }. The big issue with JSON though is that you'll always have to read and write the entire file (even when you are parsing data yourself). I'd suggest looking into how databases handle this if you'd like to learn about such things :)

Comment: Thank you for this approach and the suggestion. I'll look into some key-value paired database mechanism so that I could get some idea. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For making these types of data changes, USE DB, for JSON files you have to store full data in the variable and perform the operations.